# Fail to import Alpha_vantage.timesseries

Tags: python, alpha-vantage, import-module

EDIT: When I wrote this post I was a beginner on Stackoverflow and in programming generally. I don't remember how I solved this inquiry unfortunately. How can I close this post?

I am having trouble working with this specific module. At first, I had a problem importing alpha vantage but I could install it with the following line: python3 -m pip install alpha_vantage.py( If I tried to install it like this: pip install alphavantage - That did not work.

So now it is working however I need to work with alpha_vantage.timeseries and it doesn't work. If I import the "timeseries" separately, it works but is not linked to the alpha_vantage?! So it doesn't work.

Do you know how can I make it work?

[image: Code snippet]

Comment: The Alpaha Vantage installation can be deployed in the following ways `pip install alpha_vantage` Which library is the timeseries you are specifying?
If it is a pandas Series, there is no need to import it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you import `TimesSeries` from `alpha_vantage.timeseries`.
Please note that you have an extra `s` in TimeSeries.

- It should be TimeSeries and **not** Time**s**Series

Here is an example from their [website](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage)

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
```

Comment: Hey @ScottC, unfortunately I don't remember anymore what was the exact problem here, but anyway, I accepted you answer, and thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score -1):

I just went to another direction and used other library.

EDIT: When I wrote this post I was a beginner on Stackoverflow and in programming generally. I don't remember how I solved this inquiry unfortunately. How can I close this post?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33123538)

Comment: I updated it. Thank you. Shall I delete this comment, then?